how to use pdfium library merge pdf files
I have two pdf files(1.pdf and 2.pdf), I try to use pdfium library these two files with c++ code, but merge file contents are incorrect, I don't know why, this is my code:
void gcutMergePDF(const OdUtf8String &mergePath, const OdUtf8StringArray &array)
{
  FPDF_InitLibrary();

  FPDF_DOCUMENT output = FPDF_CreateNewDocument();
  if (!output)
  {
    ELOG("create merge file %s failed", mergePath.c_str());
    return;
  }

  int index = 0;

  for (const auto &item : array)
  {
    ELOG("add file %s to zip", item.c_str());

    FPDF_DOCUMENT pdf = FPDF_LoadDocument(item.c_str(), NULL);
    if (!pdf)
    {
      ELOG("load file %s failed", item.c_str());
      continue;
    }

    int pageCount = FPDF_GetPageCount(pdf);
    for (int i = 0; i < pageCount; ++i)
    {
      FPDF_PAGE page = FPDF_LoadPage(pdf, i);
      if (!page)
      {
        ELOG("load file %s page %d failed", item.c_str(), i);
        continue;
      }

      double width = FPDF_GetPageWidth(page);
      double height = FPDF_GetPageHeight(page);
      FPDF_PAGE newPage = FPDFPage_New(output, index, width, height);
      if (!newPage)
      {
        ELOG("new page %d failed", index);
        continue;
      }

      int count = FPDFPage_CountObjects(page);
      for (int j = 0; j < count; j++)
      {
        FPDF_PAGEOBJECT object = FPDFPage_GetObject(page, j);
        if (!object)
        {
          FPDFPage_InsertObject(newPage, object);
          FPDFPage_GenerateContent(newPage);
        }
      }
      
      FPDF_ClosePage(newPage);

      FPDF_ClosePage(page);

      index++;
    }

    FPDF_CloseDocument(pdf);
  }

  FPDF_FILEWRITE writer; 
  writer.version = 1;
  writer.WriteBlock = blockWriter;
  FPDF_SaveAsCopy(output, &writer, FPDF_NO_INCREMENTAL);

  FPDF_CloseDocument(output);

  FPDF_DestroyLibrary();
}

I hope merge file include 1.pdf and 2.pdf contents, but execute this code, merge file contents are null, could somebody give me suggests?

You should check the return value of function FPDFPage_GenerateContent.

You have a typo in if (!object)

Because if (!object) is wrong. You're telling it only to do something if the object creation fails. You should learn to use the debugger. Using it to step through the code line by line would have quickly shown you that the if statement was not being entered, which would have allowed you to figure out the problem yourself. The debugger is the best tool a coder has available to spot logic errors and trace the flow of execution. It's never too early to learn to use it.

I later modified the code, but the generated PDF is still empty

You might consider having a look at the FPDF_ImportPages api found in the fpdf_ppo.h public header. I think it might do most of the heavy lifting of what you are trying to do
